# I need some hints to solve $ \int \frac{1}{e^{2x}+2} dx $

Tags: integration

I tried with the most intuitive substitutions, but I don't see they're working...

$$ \int \frac{1}{e^{2x}+2} dx $$

Comment: $u = \sqrt 2 e^x?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet simpler:

$$ \int \frac{1}{e^{2x}+2} dx= \int \frac{e^{-2x}}{1+2e^{-2x}} dx =-\frac14\ln(1+2e^{-2x})+C.$$

Comment: ...which can be rewritten in another form, using the fact that $e^{-2x}=\frac1{e^{2x}}$ and the fact that $\ln(\frac ab)=\ln a-\ln b$. So, if you see it in another form, don't freak out.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int \frac{1}{e^{2x}+2} \, dx = \int \frac{e^{-x}}{e^x + 2e^{-x}} \,dx = \int\frac{-du}{\frac 1 u + 2u} = -\int\frac{u\,du}{1 + 2u^2}
$$
Then another, simpler, substitution does the rest.

Answer (score 2):

If $y = e^{2x}$ then your integral becomes 
$$
\int \frac{1/2}{y^2 + 2y} dy = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{y(y+2)} dy
$$
Then use partial fractions.

Comment: If $y=e^{2x}$ then $dy=2e^{2x}\,dx = 2y\,dx$ so $dy/(2y) = dx$.  Then the integral becomes
$\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{y^2+2}\,\frac{dy}{2y}$. (And then go ahead with partial fractions.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Also, why not just write $y^2+2y=y(y+2)$ and then apply partial fractions without that next substitution? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If $u=e^{2x}$ then I get $\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{du}{u^2+2u} $. I must be doing something wrong in the middle but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You're right, except the integral becomes $\int \frac{1}{y + 2} \frac{dy}{2y}$, not what you wrote.